# element.xml provision file in pages library

Tags: library

i can provision a aspx page using the element.xml in the modules folder.

But how can i do to provision a html file that would contains code into a page library?

```
<Module Name="myModuleName" SetupPath="SiteTemplates\SPS" Url="Pages" >
        <File Path="default.aspx" Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
            <Property Name="Title" Value="PmyTitle" />
            <Property Name="ContentType" Value="My Location Page" />
            <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/rich.aspx, My Location Page Layout" />
            <Property Name="PublishingPageContent" Value="" />
        </File>

    </Module>
```

Comment: You can provision files of any type to SharePoint document libraries, using same CAML. There is no difference... Have you tried similar code pointing to the html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the html file containing the markup into the module as normal, don't specify any properties other than title, it will use the deault content type.

```
<Module Name="myModuleName" Url="Pages" >
    <File Path="default.html" Url="default.html" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="Title" Value="PmyTitle" />
    </File>
</Module>
```

To serve the raw html file you'll need to change the file handling for the web app to permissive.

If you'd like to put content into a provisioned aspx page then html encode the content:

```
<Module Name="myModuleName" SetupPath="SiteTemplates\SPS" Url="Pages" >
    <File Path="default.aspx" Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
        <Property Name="Title" Value="PmyTitle" />
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="My Location Page" />
        <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/rich.aspx, My Location Page Layout" />
        <Property Name="PublishingPageContent" Value="&lt;div&gt; HTML encoded content goes here &amp; rocks! &lt;/div&gt;" />
    </File>
</Module>
```

Comment: thanks but can i provision a html file with code?

Comment: You need to put the default.html file containing your markup into a module and provision using the first of my code samples there. I am of course assuming that you only mean HTML and javascript as code.